# GWT - ClientBundle for CSS file not working with class names

Tags: css, gwt, classname, clientbundle, cssresource

I have a GWT-question,

I am trying to move my css to ClientBundle as CssResource as it claims being the best practice, but there is a problem. It does work with element-ID and element-name but not with class names. So it works when I have

```
div{
   color: red;
}
#whatever_id{
   color: black;
}
```

But if I add a class name with a dot (.) as

```
div{
   color: red;
}
#whatever_id{
   color: black;
}
.whatever_classname{
   color: green;
}
```

Then I get following excepssion

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception

    Exception while loading module com.acatime.edutime.client.edutime. See Development Mode for details.



java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.acatime.edutime.client.edutime.onModuleLoad(edutime.java:29)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.acatime.edutime.client.resources.GeneralResources' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
        at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:72)
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
        at com.acatime.edutime.client.resources.GeneralResources.<clinit>(GeneralResources.java:11)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:610)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:470)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
        ... 13 more
```

Any idea what I am missing???

Comment: By the way, I disagree that using ClientBundle for CSS is the best practice. A single CSS file is much easier to maintain, you don't need to recompile the code to make small changes, and designers can work with it directly - these are good reasons to stay with the CSS file.

Comment: have you changed `whatever_classname` in your `Java CssResource` as well as `ui.xml` file? may be you have missed to map it properly everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a problem with class names containing underscores. Try class names without underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrei and Braj for your answers. I found what I was missing.

The thing I didn't get it from the beginning was that I was adding class name as following:

```
myWidget.setStyleName("whateverClassname);
```

And that was obviously the problem. It looks like when you are using CSS through ClientBundle/CssResource then you have to designate the class name as following:

myWidget.setStyleName(MyResources.INSTANCE.myCss().whateverClassname());

And da da, suddenly everything working just fine :) I hope now this is the right way adding style to a GWT app. I'm kind of newbie in GWT and trying to follow the best practices recommended at GWT's website.